# jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException table or view does not exist. Tested query in database, works. But web application errors

Tags: sql, oracle, spring, jdbc

> **EDIT: FIXED! Look below**

So I have tested the query in SQL Developer and it works fine. However, in my implementation, the run does not load the data into the list and spits out this error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad
>       SQL grammar [select columnname,displayname, viewsortorder,capsdisind,window, DIS
>       FIELDID , (select  1 from WEB_CUSTDISABLEDFIELDS where custid =? AND  A.DISFIELD
>       ID  = WEB_CUSTDISABLEDFIELDS.DISFIELDID) from web_DISABLEDFIELDS  A ]; nested ex
>       ception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.d
>       oTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:220)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslat
>       or.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:
>       607)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:64
>       1)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:67
>       0)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:67
>       8)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:71
>       0)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>               at flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.invoke(JavaAdap
>       ter.java:421)
>               at flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingServic
>       e.java:183)
>               at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java
>       :1503)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndp
>       oint.java:884)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBroker
>       Filter.java:121)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:15
>       8)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:
>       44)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFi
>       lter.java:67)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(Serialization
>       Filter.java:146)
>               at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.ja
>       va:278)
>               at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java
>       :322)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>       icationFilterChain.java:304)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>       ilterChain.java:210)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
>       alve.java:224)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
>       alve.java:175)
>               at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
>       torBase.java:472)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
>       ava:164)
>               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
>       ava:100)
>               at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
>       929)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
>       ve.java:118)
>               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
>       a:405)
>               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcesso
>       r.java:316)
>               at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
>       AbstractProtocol.java:515)
>               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
>       t.java:1544)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.ja
>       va:91)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:1
>       12)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
>       :173)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.
>       java:194)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPrepare
>       dStatement.java:785)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPrepa
>       redStatement.java:860)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStateme
>       nt.java:1186)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePrep
>       aredStatement.java:3381)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePrepare
>       dStatement.java:3425)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(Oracle
>       PreparedStatementWrapper.java:1490)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(Jd
>       bcTemplate.java:648)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:
>       591)
>               ... 39 more

I've searched multiple problems with this error but none of them seem to address the same issue as mines. I am using Oracle SQL.

Maybe someone has ran into this problem before? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**FIXED THE PROBLEM**

The issue was the tables. They just needed permissions in the database to be accessed.

What I did was this:

```
grant all on sa.table to public
/
create public synonym table for sa.table
/
grant all on sa.table2 to public
/
create public synonym table2 for sa.table2
/
```

Comment: Found the problem:

The issue was the tables. They just needed permissions in the database to be accessed.

What I did was this:


    `grant all on sa.table to public
    /
    create public synonym table for sa.table
    /
    grant all on sa.table2 to public
    /
    create public synonym table2 for sa.table2
    /`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your web app is logging into a different schema than your table

Try specifying the schema explictly in the sql statement. i.e. :

```
SELECT a, b FROM user.TABLE
```